# How to create secure https server in "Qt"?

Tags: c++, qt, https

I am going through the below github source code for implementation of rest server. It has details with respect to http server but when I am trying to create a secure server I am facing problem after adding the certificate and key. Please suggest how to establish a secure https server using Qt.
https://github.com/Tropby/QSimpleRestServer

```
    QFile certFile("demo.cer");
    QFile keyFile("demo.key");
    QByteArray cert,key;
    if(!certFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        qDebug() << "Couldn't Open Resource File.";
        qDebug() << "Error: " << certFile.errorString();
    }
else {
    cert = certFile.readAll();
    certFile.close();

}

    if(!keyFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        qDebug() << "Couldn't Open Resource File.";
        qDebug() << "Error: " << keyFile.errorString();
    }
    else {
        key = keyFile.readAll();
        keyFile.close();

    }
    if(sslSocket->setSocketDescriptor(socket_descriptor)){
        qDebug()<<"set passed";
    } else {
        qDebug()<<"set failed";
    }
    
    sslSocket->setProtocol(QSsl::AnyProtocol);
    sslSocket->ignoreSslErrors();
    QSslKey ssl_key(key,QSsl::Rsa,QSsl::Pem,QSsl::PrivateKey,(QByteArray)"demo.key");
    QSslCertificate ssl_cert(cert);
    sslSocket->setLocalCertificate(cert);
    sslSocket->setPrivateKey(ssl_key);

    sslSocket->modeChanged(QSslSocket::SslMode::SslServerMode);
    sslSocket->startServerEncryption();
```

Comment: what problem are you facing?? errors at runtime, compilationTime? is really hard to help you withput that information

Comment: After adding the cerificate and key, When I am calling startServerEncryption() application is crashing

Comment: Use the debugger to find where it crashes.